# Does PowerShell splatting support inline hashtable?

Tags: powershell

I want to use splatting syntax, but I want to do it inline

So instead of:

```
$p = @{Path = '.'}
ls @p
```

I want to do

```
ls @@{Path = '.'}
```

but this is a syntax error.
Is there anyway to splat a hashtable without having to write a separate variable?

Why do I want to do this?  I prefer the hashtable syntax for defining alot of parameters (like 4 or more).  But I'd rather not define a variable, I just want to have the cmdlet I'm calling at the "top" of the hashtable definition.

Comment: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869/suggestions/11708589

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The splat operator will look for a variable whose name matches the characters after the splat sign, it doesn't try to resolve the characters after the sign as a statement to get the value. You cant do it inline. Link to [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As Francois mentioned, this is not possible yet, however, there are some discussions taking place around adding expanded splatting functionality (including this feature specifically) in the PowerShell RFC repository on GitHub:

- RFC: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/blob/master/1-Draft/RFC0002-Generalized-Splatting.md
- Discussion: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/issues/6